# How to left align certain equations in MathJax

Tags: javascript, mathjax

So, by default MathJax equations are centered, but I want to left align certain equations.  I know how to make ALL equations left aligned with MathJax.Hub.Config, but this is not what I want.

I've tried other code found on the web, such as the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(function () {
      MathJax.Hub.Config({displayAlign:"left"});
      MathJax.Hub.Typeset(["leqn"]);
    });
 </script>
```

then wrapped a div around the equation with an id of leqn, like so:

```
<div id="leqn">$$e^{\pi i} - 1 = 0$$</div>
```

This does not work and I don't know enough about MathJax or even JS to have any idea as to what I'm doing wrong.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no elegant way for doing this using TeX input. The approach will vary with the use cases. Here you seem to be able to wrap HTML around those equations you want to align to the left. For this you are generally on the right track. Here's what would need fixing:

- use the correct way of hooking into MathJax's internals
- have MathJax ignore the relevant equations on the first round of typesetting by adding `class="tex2jax_ignore"`
- remove that class, change the configuration, and have MathJax typeset the rest

Below is one way of doing that.

- You can configure other class names, [see the docs](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/tex2jax.html).
- It's a bit more complicated because of SO's restrictions on external resources in snippets (no query strings allowed so I'm injecting it "manually") -- in your page, just use the `window.MathJax` part and load it before you load `MathJax.js`.

```js
      window.MathJax = {
        AuthorInit: function() {
          MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("Begin", function() {
            MathJax.Hub.Queue(function() {
              var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('tex2jax_ignore');
              for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                elements[i].classList.remove('tex2jax_ignore');
              }
              MathJax.Hub.Config({
                displayAlign: "left"
              });
              MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]);
            });
          });
        }
      };

      (function(d, script) {
        script = d.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full';
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
      }(document));
```

```html
$$e^{\pi i} - 1 = 0$$
<span class="tex2jax_ignore">$$e^{\pi i} - 1 = 0$$</span>
$$e^{\pi i} - 1 = 0$$
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your original approach didn't work is that the equation has already been typeset during the initial typesetting pass performed by MathJax, and your call to `MathJax.Hub.Typeset()` doesn't re-typeset existing math, but only typesets *new* math since the last typeset call.  So the math is left as it was.

Instead, you could use `MathJax.Hub.Rerender(["leqn"])` to have the math re-rendered with the new `displayAlign` setting.

That being said, Peter's approach is better, since it doesn't require the math to be typeset twice.  I provide a slight refinement to his approach below.  Rather than using `tex2jax_ignore` and having to go back and remove that from all the elements that have that class, you can add `leqn` to the ignored classes, and then remove it again before the second typesetting pass.  Here is the code:

```js
MathJax = {
  tex2jax: {ignoreClass: "tex2jax_ignore|leqn"},
  AuthorInit: function() {
    MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("End",function () {
      MathJax.Hub.Queue(function () {
        MathJax.Hub.Config({
          tex2jax: {ignoreClass: "tex2jax_ignore"},
          displayAlign: "left"
        });
        return MathJax.Hub.Typeset();
      });
    });
  }
};

(function(d, script) {
  script = d.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full';
  d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}(document));
```

```html
$$e^{\pi i} - 1 = 0$$
<span class="leqn">$$e^{\pi i} - 1 = 0$$</span>
$$e^{\pi i} - 1 = 0$$
```

**EDIT**:  Here is another approach that uses a post-filter for the TeX input jax that sets the `indentalign` property of the underlying MathML based on the class of the parent element (you could also use ID, but remember that ID's need to be unique, so you would have to use a different ID for each equation, which is why classes are better).

```js
MathJax = {
  AuthorInit: function() {
    MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("TeX Jax Ready",function () {
      MathJax.InputJax.TeX.postfilterHooks.Add(function (data) {
        if (data.script.parentNode.className === "leqn")
          data.math.root.indentalign = "left";
      });
    });
  }
};

(function(d, script) {
  script = d.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full';
  d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}(document));
```

```html
$$e^{\pi i} - 1 = 0$$
<span class="leqn">$$e^{\pi i} - 1 = 0$$</span>
$$e^{\pi i} - 1 = 0$$
```

It would also be possible to add a macro to the TeX input jax that would allow you to specify the `indentalign` property, but that would be a little more work.

Comment: Just a small note that he's using an id for leqn

Comment: True, but to use either of our methods he must use a class.  I should have pointed that out, thanks.

Comment: No worries. But totally unfair how your answer ranks ahead of mine ;-)

Comment: I think that equally voted answers get ordered randomly.  It seems to change when I leave and reload the page later. I'll up vote you to break the tie.

Comment: Thanks @DavideCervone for your addition.  Both solutions worked perfectly...  but how ugly!

Out of curiosity, why is it so difficult to do such a simple thing?  Is this a limitation with MathJax or with TeX typesetting?

Comment: The positioning of equations in LaTeX usually is set up by the document style that is specified in the LaTeX document, so it would be unusual to have some equations centers and others flush left.  For individual displayed equations, you might be able to use `\hfill` to force them to the left, but that probably wouldn't work with some alignment environments, and MathJax doesn't implement `\hfill` anyway.  The upshot is that TeX really doesn't have (that I know of) a standard way to do this, and so neither does MathJax.

Comment: The multiline environment does have `\shoveleft` and `\shoveright`, so those could possibly be used.  MathML, the markup language underlying MathJax, does have an attribute that can be used to set the alignment on an equation by equation basis, so one could arrange for the TeX input to be able to set that, but there isn't currently a way to do it.  I'll add an example of how you could do that to my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding css style might do the work:

```
<style>
    mjx-container {text-align: left !important;}
</style>
```