# Different properties for different delimiters?

Tags: html, delimiter, mathjax

I know that I can specify delimiters like so

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    "tex2jax": {
        displayMath: [["$$", "$$"], ["\\(", "\\)"]],
        inlineMath: [["$", "$"]]
    }
});
```

**My question is whether it is possible to assign different properties / stylesheets to different delimiters?** In my case I want formulas surrounded with `$$` to be centered (which seems to be the default) and formulas surounded with `\(` and `\)` to be left aligned.

Comment: Some alternative approaches are given in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30077862/how-to-left-align-certain-equations-in-mathjax/30100709#30100709).  Note that the answer below only works for the HTML-CSS output, whereas the ones I link to work for all output modes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a way to modify `tex2jax` processor and add new types of display with their own `delimiters`, but there's an easier way to achieve pretty much the same result, using `classes` and `styles` that you can easily add to the `config` object. Like this for example, you only need to add class left to the `MathJax` elements you want aligned left.

```js
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    "tex2jax": {
        displayMath: [
            ["$$", "$$"],
            ["\\(", "\\)"]
        ],
        inlineMath: [
            ["$", "$"]
        ]
    },
    displayAlign: "",
    "HTML-CSS": {
        styles: {
            ".left .MathJax_Display": {
                "text-align": "left"
            }
        }
    }

});
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
<p class="left">$$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$</p>
<p>$$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$</p>
```

This requires that you put your MathJax between tags.

EDIT:

You can also change the default styles, so you could override some of .MathJax_Display properties the same way. Like this:

```js
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    "tex2jax": {
        displayMath: [
            ["$$", "$$"],
            ["\\(", "\\)"]
        ],
        inlineMath: [
            ["$", "$"]
        ]
    },
    displayAlign: "",
    "HTML-CSS": {
        styles: {
            ".left .MathJax_Display": {
                "text-align": "left"
            },
            ".MathJax_Display":{
                "text-align": "right"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
<p class="left">$$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$</p>
<p>$$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$</p>
```

Comment: Your example just works perfectly fine, but on my page it doesn't. MathJax actually generates the css class with `text-align: left`, but it also generates `style="text-align: center;"` for every `MathJax_Display` element.

Comment: @Cubinator73 That's because .MathJax_Display is in the default config, but you can override it. See edit.

Comment: Now it works perfectly fine. Thank you :) (+1 for the example code)

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.